# FlowLayout add under previous components

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, flowlayout, jseparator

I'm trying to add somes components to a `JPanel` in `flowLayout`.

```
JPanel panelPrincipal = new JPanel();
principale.getContentPane().add(panelPrincipal, BorderLayout.CENTER);
panelPrincipal.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

JPanel panelDynamique = new JPanel();
JScrollPane jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(panelDynamique);
panelPrincipal.add(jScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

if(this.getNbAppFor(champs.get(6)) > 0) {
    JLabel lblMAJ = new JLabel(champs.get(6));
    panelDynamique.add(lblMAJ);
    panelDynamique.add(new JSeparator());

    JPanel panelMAJ = new JPanel();
    panelMAJ.setLayout(new GridLayout(this.getNbAppFor(champs.get(6))/2, 2));
    panelDynamique.add(panelMAJ);
}

if(this.getNbAppFor(champs.get(7)) > 0) {
    JLabel lblDispo = new JLabel(champs.get(7));
    panelDynamique.add(new JSeparator());

    JPanel panelDispo = new JPanel();
    panelDispo.setLayout(new GridLayout(this.getNbAppFor(champs.get(7))/2, 2));
    panelDynamique.add(panelDispo);
}
```

It's the core build, but it doesn't look how I expected.

I made an illustration of what I'm trying to do:

[image: Result Expected]

How can I add a component to a `FlowLayout` in a next "row" under the previous component? And how can I make my separators fill the width of my `Container`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

according to your drawing, but not used FlowLayout.

```
package testp;

import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;

public class LayTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        c.weightx = 1;
        p.add(new JLabel("Mide a jour"), c);

        c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        p.add(new JSeparator(), c);

        c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        p.add(new JPanel(), c);

        c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 3;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        p.add(new JSeparator(), c);

        c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 4;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        p.add(new JLabel("Disponsible"), c);

        c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 5;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        p.add(new JSeparator(), c);

        c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 6;
        c.weighty = 1;
        p.add(new JPanel(), c);


        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setSize(300, 400);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setContentPane(p);
        f.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

you may find useful 
[oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: Hi ! Your answer seems to works like I want ! I'll try to make it works with my code. Thanks a lot !

Comment: i had another problem with your code, i posted a new question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34731570/java-issue-with-gridbaglayout-gridlayout
if you have some time, your help should be really appreciated. Thanks anyway for your help for my first problem :)